# Cant get image src with cheerio

Tags: node.js, cheerio

Im trying to put togheder a **scraper** with nodejs and cheerio.
i have this so far:

```
class ScraperService {

    static getDwelling(url) {
        const dwelling = {
            images: []
        };
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request(`https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/${url}`, (err, resp, html) => {
                if(err || resp.statusCode === 404) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                const $ = cheerio.load(html);
                pe = $('.price-operation', '#article-container').text();
                dwelling.price = $('.price-items', '#article-container').text();
                dwelling.description = $('.description-container', '#article-container').html();
                //getting images here
                $('#tab-foto-flickity').find('img').each(() => {dwelling.images.push(this);});
                resolve(dwelling);
            });
        });
    }
}

module.exports = ScraperService;
```

the problem is im getting 37 nulls insted of the link the the images, i have tried different tags but no luck. Any ideas where is the code failing
[image: Code to scrape]

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting nulls is due to the use of arrow functions `() =>{}` in the `each` callback. 
Arrow function *do not* have a `this`. Try using a classic anonymous function.

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions